# Use External Java Library in Android

Tags: java, android, unirest, mashape

I have to use one of [mashape](https://www.mashape.com/) api in my android application, for that I have to include their java support library named [unirest](http://unirest.io/java) to my android project, I have added that library via build configuration settings. but when I run the project it throws ***java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError***
 and stops application.is there any way to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

when using third-party libs on android you should follow these steps:

1. **right click** on your **project**
2. select **properties** from the menu
3. in the new window select **Java build path**
4. in  **Order and export** tab make sure that the libraries are checked
5. click ok and run

[image]

Comment: have you tried to move your third-party libs all the way up?

Comment: yes, it is not about that problem, I think android and java uses different byte code format, may be that's the problem.